# Internal Server Error - Python CGI

Tags: java, python, cgi, popen, internal-server-error

I am currently writing a CGI script that has an end goal of running a java program and then redirecting to a different page.  However, the CGI causes a 500 internal server error when I call try to run the java program.  I've tried os.system("[command]") and call(["command"]) and subprocess.Popen("command") and all three cause the same issue to crop up.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**Edit** Also, the apache log gives me next to no information saying only that there is an invalid header.

**Edit**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import the CGI module
import cgi
import random
import os
import sys
import re
import subprocess

# Required header that tells the browser how to render the HTML.
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
userID = random.random()
print "<html>"
print "<title>Results</title>"
print "<body>"

command = "java [classname] "
user_id = random.randint(0, sys.maxint)
command += str(user_id) + " "
command +=  re.sub(r'\s', '', form['key0'].value) + " "
command += form['key1'].value + " "
command += form['key2'].value + " "
command += form['key3'].value + " " if form.has_key('key3') else "0 "

## This is where the problem exists
#os.system("ls -l")
#call(["ls", "-l"])
#p = subprocess.Popen(command)
## End of Problem

print command   
print "<br>"
print "Redirecting..."

print "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=",
print "http://192.168.1.41/Path/",
print user_id,
print ".html' />" 


print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

the entire command is not there, but I believe it is built correctly because I can copy the printed command out and run it in a terminal and it runs perfectly.  The command is simply java [classname] [9 args]

the java code runs smoothly outside of the python code and all it does is generate a .png file and a .html file containing the .png.  The name of the file is [user_id].html, hence the redirect.

the internal server error does **not** occur if only the process commands are commented out.

**EDIT** Ended up giving up and moving to php to execute this script.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: could you post your code? looks like there is error in your code or you code does not generate http headers first.

Comment: only some of it.  I'll do what I can.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()
```

to get a more meaningful error - python error message in your browser

or

running your script from the command line on your server to see if python is returning an error, and if so, if it helps to diagnose the problem?

or

printing your java call as html output from your python script?

Comment: No clearer errors came out of enabling this.  Just [127.0.0.1] malformed header in the /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 1):

```
## This is where the problem exists
#os.system("ls -l")
#call(["ls", "-l"])
#p = subprocess.Popen(command)
## End of Problem
```

1. Focus on `subprocess.Popen`.  Discard all others.  Permanently.  They're all bad ideas.
2. If `subprocess.Popen(command)` really does work as a stand-alone short Python script, then you have to investigate whether or not the Apache CGI-bin username has the required privileges to run this.  Remember.  Apache doesn't run as you.  It runs as a separate "person" with separate privileges.
3. Your java command is probably spewing data into sys.stdout and or sys.stderr.  If so, that output goes to Apache.  Ideally, some stuff has already gone to Apache via sys.stdout which is a proper header and everything's good.

   However, because of the way things are buffered, there's a small chance that Apache has seen no useable response and the java output is confusing.

I'd suggest that you switch to `mod_wsgi` instead of CGI because it's easier to control.

I'd also suggest that you capture the subprocess output in a file and then copy that file to sys.stdout so that Apache can't be confused by the java subprocess.

Comment: All three of those lines are different ways of running an executable from inside the program.  All three work when not being run from the server and only one is used at a time.  As of that code block, all three are commented out because I can't run the site if they are in it.

Comment: Call comes from "from subprocess import call"

Comment: @mrK: That's a question of Linux sys administration.  `chmod ugo+x some_file.py` will grant execute privileges.  But Apache has a set of filters so that files owned by root never get executed.

Comment: So if I chown to me it might work?  I think they might be owned by root at the moment